# How Non-Clustered affects Clustered Index (PK)

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

```
Columns          | Data Type     | Allow Null
-----------------|---------------|-----------
Id (PK)          | int           | Unchecked
                 |               |  
Type             | tinyint       | Unchecked
                 |               |
Severity         | tinyint       | Unchecked
                 |               |
Message          | varchar(1000) | Unchecked
                 |               |
ReferenceTypeId  | int           | Checked
                 |               |
ReferenceId      | int           | Checked
                 |               |
ParentId         | int           | Checked
                 |               |
ParentTypeId     | int           | Checked
                 |               |
Created          | datetime      | Checked
```

Okay, in the above table I have **10996674** records. When i run the following Query `select count(id) from DTL_Event` it takes 1:23 mins.

After applying Indexing

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX DTL_Event_Optimization_Date on DTL_Event([Created])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX DTL_Event_Optimization_TypeIds_Composite on DTL_Event([ReferenceTypeId],[ParentTypeId])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX DTL_Event_Optimization_Reference_Parent_Ids_Composite on DTL_Event([ReferenceId],[ParentId])
```

The same query `select count(id) from DTL_Event` takes 1 sec. I need to know why, because Id is a primary key which supposed to be indexed already and I am applying indexing on other columns thats why i have a Question:

> Why NonClustered Indexing on other Columns optimizes this query
>   `select count(id) from DTL_Event`. i.e. Why applying Nonclustered indexing on other columns helps me faster retrieval of **count of Id(s)**

Comment: Have you had a look at the query plan before and after you new indexes? They might give a hint at what is going on.

Comment: Is your question about MySQL or SQL Server? You have both tagged.

Comment: Its about SQL, sorry made a mistake

Comment: `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` and the magic disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding a nonclustered index QO is choosing one of non clustered clustered index 
 simply because that is most efficient way to do because of "page count" in the index.

QO might choose (most of the time) NON-clustered index with the lowest page count overall.

As you might know nonclustered indexes has unique identifier for lookup in the other indexes/heap in the leaf level.

> Why NonClustered Indexing on other Columns optimizes this query 
>   select count(id) from DTL_Event. i.e. Why applying Nonclustered
>   indexing on other columns helps me faster retrieval of count of Id(s)

In your case that is you primary (clustered and unique) key ID,
 *so every nonclustered has ID column in the leaf level*
 for example you create a nonclustered index like

```
>   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX DTL_Event_Optimization_Date on
> DTL_Event([Created])
```

Then it will automatically include column ID

```
>   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX DTL_Event_Optimization_Date on
> DTL_Event([Created]) 
> INCLUDE (ID)
```

So actually after adding nonclustered index its quite efficient to look on one of the nonclustered index for the rowcount instead of looking on to clustered index you can look into the same in execution plan

TEST RIG :

```
CREATE Table DTL_Event (ID INT not null , TYPE tinyint not null  , Severity tinyint  not null ,[Message] varchar(1000) not null , ReferenceTypeId int ,ReferenceId int

 ,ParentId int , ParentTypeId int ,Created datetime   , primary key (ID))
```

**Without Non-clustered indeX**

```
  select count(id) from DTL_Event
```

**EXECUTION PLAN**
[image]

**WITH NONCLUSTERED INDEX**

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX DTL_Event_Optimization_Date on DTL_Event([Created])



select count(id) from DTL_Event
```

**EXECUTION PLAN**
[image]

BUT if your goal is to count total number of rows present in the table best way is to do that

```
SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('Transactions')   
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1);
```

Comment: You answer is not satisfying my question :(

Comment: please ask again i might not understand fully go on

Comment: First of all you have not created Id as PK. and Nonclustered Indexing on other columns, somehow relates to ID? thats why Count(ID) is faster after indexing?

Comment: Hey @WaqarAhmed look into Create table DDL in the end , i have declared "ID" as primary key.
and yes all the nonclustered index as related to ID.
ALL the NONCUSTERED INDEX has ID on there LEAF LEVEL 
LIKE


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX DTL_Event_Optimization_Date on DTL_Event([Created])
INCLUDE (ID)

Comment: WHETHER  you include or not if you have primary key(UNIQUE-CLUSTERED) on the table then ALL of your NON-CLUSTERED INDEX WILL HAVE TO ALL ID ON THE LEAF LEVEL

Comment: hey @WaqarAhmed i am open for any question you can go  on

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if your pk is also the clustered index, it will also live at the leaf level of any non-clustered indexes. Conversely, all of the table data lives at the leaf level of the clustered index. So, if you're just asking for a count, one of your non-clustered indexes is likely going to be narrower than the clustered and can satisfy the query, so the optimizer will choose that. However, if you add a where clause, all bets are off.

Comment: Is that suppose to answer my question? I don't get your answer.

Comment: Hit submit before it was done accidentally; check now.

Comment: Umm so you are saying If I select some data or count(*) using where clause, After indexing ofc, It will not be faster?

Comment: It depends on whether the index supports it or not. For example, if you say `where Created > '2016-01-01'`, your index on the created column will be able to fully satisfy that query. However, if you say `where message like 'foobar%'` then you don't currently have an index that is able to satisfy that.